# Ucommerce parse niceurl or set context

Tags: umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I'm trying to get the current category from the url e.g. http://localhost/catalog/discs/c-24/c-92 (generated from GetNiceUrlForCategory()). But when I call `SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentCategory`, returns null.

`SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentCatalogue` and `SiteContext.Current.CatalogContext.CurrentCatalogueGroup` do not return null.

Is there another internal call where I can parse the URL or should I write my own?
Can I set the context from the URL?

Answer (score 0):

Check hostnames, it looks like they are not set for localhost